# Stimulsoft How do i remove the duplication of these lines?

Tags: sql, duplicates, stimulsoft

So I am currently working on reworking a report so that the report can show the quantity that has been ordered per day. It used to show the order ID and quantity of each order per line.

As it can be seen in the picture below i got it calculate the total quantity of each product per day. My problem is that it keeps duplicating the summed up quantity as if it is still going through it on an order per order basis.

[Example of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz61r.png)

The way I see it I could solve this in both sql and hopefully the Stimulsoft designer. So I was wondering if anyone out there who knows stimulsoft better than me(trust me it does not take much) could maybe give a few tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving what was being printed to the group header band instead of having it in the databand. Because the stored procedure/table's primary key was the Order Id the databand would print/display a line for each row. The group header band on the other hand does not.

TLDR; moved what needed to be displayed to the Group Header Band.

Comment: so thnaks your question and answer fix things for me